# Have Total Commander notice file changes when using FTP

Tags: ftp, comparison, total-commander

I'm using Total Commander to copy compiled files to a server with FTP, but Total Commander often misses changed files during comparing if the file sizes haven't changed. Since I'm using FTP I can't compare files by content. Also, the time on the server is inconsistent with my system time, so comparing by time and date is out, as well.
Is there a way to "mark" my files so Total Commander knows/thinks they have changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with standard options within TC. I haven't even encountered any plugins that can help you with the same.

Answer (score 0):

Total Commander 7.55 and above support MLSD, so it can compare by date/time reliably.

In order for it to work, the server must support MFMT, MDTM or SITE UTIME to set the file time on the server.

Comment: Ah, that's cool! But as it isn't an actual answer to the question, I won't mark it as such. :P